# Vue.prototypeでもグローバルなデータは管理できますが、Vuexを使う理由は開発者ツールによりログが閲覧できることなのでしょうか？

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Vuexを使うメリットについて質問です。
「Vuex メリット」などで調べるとデータの一元管理などが挙げられている記事が見つかりますが、そのようなことは下記コードでも実装できるかと思います。

```
Vue.prototype.$selfStore = new Vue({
    data: {
        count: 0,
    },
    methods: {
        increment() {
            this.count++;
        }
    },
});
```

Vuexのマニュアルも一通り読みましたが、機能的な面では上記のVue.prototypeにVueインスタンスを入れておくだけでも賄える内容が多いかと思います。
そのような中でわざわざVuexを使う理由というのは、やはり各履歴が開発者ツールで見られるからなのでしょうか？
Vuexも学習コストが0というわけではないので、Vuexを導入するメリットを明確にしておきたく質問いたしました。

実際に使用されている方など、メリットについてお分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答いただけますと幸いです。